# Thermometers for high temperature ovens

Tags: equipment

Are there any thermometers that you can put in clay ovens, or under a broiler? Most of the thermometers have a temperature limit of 350 ~ 400 degrees.

I actually burnt one down last year by turning the broiler on by accident.

Comment: If you want to go even hotter than Robert's answer, look for industrial thermocouples. Type K or N, for example, will get you FAR hotter than you'd ever want to cook at (unless you're cooking clay)

Comment: @derobert - I think you should include your comment as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want a [**commercial oven or high heat thermometer**](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dgarden&field-keywords=commercial+oven+thermometer&x=0&y=0).

[**This one**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0021AEAIK) goes to 750° F (about 400 C):

[image]

My [**Big Green Egg Temperature Gauge**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003EDL5S6) goes up to 750° F (about 400 C).

[image]

But if I want to monitor the internal temperature of what you are cooking in a hotter oven/broiler, I usually use [**a remote thermometer**](http://www.buy.com/prod/taylor-1470-digital-oven-thermometer/q/sellerid/11408470/loc/66357/204591473.html) which has an all-metal wire and probe:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, look up a scientific supply house (maybe [Fisher Scientific](http://www.fishersci.com/)). You'll be looking at more money, of course, and a lot of the stuff won't be certified as "food safe".

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar scenario, and I found this thermometer, which goes up to 550 C, so it would be apprepriate for a pizza/bread oven. It is designed to be installed in the door.

[Door Thermometer for Wood Oven](https://www.fornobravo.com/store/door-thermometer-for-wood-oven/)